How do I adjust number of shares after a stock split on google-finance?
I use google-finance to browse a portfolio.  After a stock split, the share price has adjusted correctly, but the number of shares has remained the same.
How do I adjust the number of shares, it looks like the only thing I can do is to add another transaction?

The only ways I see to adjust a portfolio on Google Finance are to delete a position and to record a transaction. Depending on whether the cost basis of the original lot was adjusted, you could either record another buy on the same date, using zero as the purchase price, or delete the original position and record a new purchase of the entire lot at the adjusted cost basis (original price adjusted for the split).
It seems that Google has not focused on creating a fully functional portfolio management tool. If this functionality is something that would benefit you, I'd look at other sites (perhaps your broker?) for more complete portfolio management.

Agreed. A usable tool should have a push-button way to do this. Or, ideally, should do it automatically.
